# How to convert signal data set of 400 samples with 5000 data points into a tensor of [400, 1, 5000] in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have 400 sensor recordings and each one is having length of 5000. I want to convert it into a tensor of [400,1,5000] or [batch_size, input_channels, signal_length] for a ML problem to train a 1DCNN network by using pytorch nn.Conv1d.

Comment: Use `torch.view()` or `torch.reshape()` functions

Answer (score 0):

This operation is often referred to as unsqueezing a dimension. There are multiple ways of achieving this, either with an explicit reshape, or with slicing tricks.

1. Using [`torch.Torch.unsqueeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html), either out-of-place:

   ```
   >>> x.unsqueeze(dim=1) # won't affect x
   ```

   Or in-place with `torch.Tensor.unsqueeze_`:

   ```
   >>> x.unsqueeze_(dim=1) # will mutate x
   ```
2. Using indexing:

   ```
   >>> x[:, None] # will insert a singleton at dim=1
   ```
3. Reshaping the tensor with [`torch.Tensor.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html):

   ```
   >>> x.reshape(len(x), 1, -1)
   ```

   This is not the recommended method as it doesn't generalize. In my opinion, you should not use `reshape` or `view` if you are not actually reshaping the tensor.